# The difference between those two SQL queries

Tags: sql

I have converted a sql query written by an other senoir developer who also is the group lead and I am new to programming. He wrote a query that was  reading a collection of rows from DB by sending array of parameters, For example:

```
SELECT [LastName],[FirstMidName],[EnrollmentDate] 
FROM [ContosoUniversity1].[dbo].[Student] 
WHERE ([LastName] ='Alexander' AND [FirstMidName] = 'Carson') 
   OR ([LastName] ='Justice' AND [FirstMidName] = 'Peggy')
```

However, I was given an assignment to improve the security of the query. I did some changes to apply `sqlParameter()` to the query. The query was written as:

```
SELECT [LastName],[FirstMidName],[EnrollmentDate] 
FROM [ContosoUniversity1].[dbo].[Student] 
WHERE [LastName] IN ('Alexander','Justice') 
  AND [FirstMidName] IN ('Carson','Peggy')
```

So basically its follows the `where.. in` clause that I can further do my other tasks. And these two lines give the same result but he insisted that mine was logically bad. I have very hard time to understand his explanation and self-doubt that if I am doing wrong to convert this query. Could anyone share any opinion?

Comment: He's right. Yours is logiically bad, because it produces different results that aren't what was intended.

Comment: Your query selects more combinations (valid and invalid ones) compared to the initial one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query will only bring in an exact grouping of names. Imagine if someone else went to the school called Carson Justice. Your query would bring him in, the seniors query would not.

I.e.

```
FirstMidName  |  LastName
Alexander     |  Carson
Peggy         |  Justice
Peggy         |  Carson
Alexander     |  Justice
```

Seniors query would return Alexander Carson, Peggy Justice

Your query would return all 4 names (Alexander Carson, Peggy Justice, Peggy Carson, Alexander Justice)

Answer (score 2):

Yours is logically wrong because it will bring in Peggy Alexander.  The first query won't bring her in.  And that doesn't seem like the intent of the exercise.